# extract data from a specific format

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, oracle11g, expression

I have data in a column which is varchar2(4000) data type in oracle 11g table.

The data looks like this,

```
"LOCT":"MA","PRICE":"10","DISPLAY_TYP": ["M","F","B"],"ID":"101","FILTER":"LTE" 

"LOCT":"NY","DISPLAY_TYP":["M","F","B"],"ID":"100","PRICE":"30","FILTER":"GTE"
```

Can someone please help me how can i do this in oracle sql.

expected output:

```
LOCT = NY 

DISPLAY_TYP = M,F,B   

ID = 100  

PRICE = >=20
```

The data needs to be extracted based on LOCT, Price,Display_typ, ID and filter  to retrieve the corresponding values.

Thanks

Comment: You should urgently consider adding code at the point at which this data is acquired to insert it into the database in a more appropriate, normalized format.  Dealing with data like this in the long term is going to be a nightmare.  In the interim you could look at the Json support in Oracle as thats what you have (sans {})

Comment: You want one SQL SELECT statement that does this or a Stored Procedure (or Function) ?

Comment: If it is feasible, then one sql select statement

Comment: @pavan Do you need the results on separate rows, and are you looking for strings (e.g. `LOCT = NY` or can they be in separate columns? It's relatively trivial to output one row per string with different columns for each item, eg. LOCT, PRICE, etc

Comment: one row per string with different columns for each item, works for me.  (LOCT=NY DISPLAY_TYP  = M,F, ID = 101, PRICE >=20 ). sometimes the format can also be like this ("LOCT":"NY","DISPLAY_TYP":["F","B"],"ID":"100","PRICE":"30","FILTER":"GTE"  ) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can separate out all the values into individual columns:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 pkey, '"LOCT":"MA","PRICE":"10","DISPLAY_TYP": ["M","F","B"],"ID":"101","FILTER":"LTE"' str from dual union all
                     select 2 pkey, '"LOCT":"NY","DISPLAY_TYP":["M","F","B"],"ID":"100","PRICE":"30","FILTER":"GTE"' str from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data containing your strings.
-- You would just run the SQL below, replacing "sample_data" with your tablename
select pkey,
       regexp_substr(str, '"LOCT":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) loct,
       regexp_substr(str, '"PRICE":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) price,
       replace(regexp_substr(str, '"DISPLAY_TYP":\s*\[(.*)\]', 1, 1, null, 1), '"') display_typ,
       regexp_substr(str, '"ID":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) id,
       regexp_substr(str, '"FILTER":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) filter
from   sample_data;

      PKEY LOCT PRICE DISPLAY_TYP     ID    FILTER
---------- ---- ----- --------------- ----- ------
         1 MA   10    M,F,B           101   LTE   
         2 NY   30    M,F,B           100   GTE
```

And here's how you could unpivot that out into separate rows:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 pkey, '"LOCT":"MA","PRICE":"10","DISPLAY_TYP": ["M","F","B"],"ID":"101","FILTER":"LTE"' str from dual union all
                     select 2 pkey, '"LOCT":"NY","DISPLAY_TYP":["M","F","B"],"ID":"100","PRICE":"30","FILTER":"GTE"' str from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data containing your strings.
-- You would just run the SQL below, replacing "sample_data" with your tablename
select pkey,
       str_part||' = '||val sub_str
from   (select pkey,
               str,
               regexp_substr(str, '"LOCT":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) loct,
               regexp_substr(str, '"PRICE":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) price,
               replace(regexp_substr(str, '"DISPLAY_TYP":\s*\[(.*)\]', 1, 1, null, 1), '"') display_typ,
               regexp_substr(str, '"ID":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) id,
               regexp_substr(str, '"FILTER":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) filter
        from   sample_data) res
unpivot (val for str_part in (loct, price, display_typ, id, filter));

      PKEY SUB_STR                            
---------- -----------------------------------
         1 LOCT = MA                          
         1 PRICE = 10                         
         1 DISPLAY_TYP = M,F,B                
         1 ID = 101                           
         1 FILTER = LTE                       
         2 LOCT = NY                          
         2 PRICE = 30                         
         2 DISPLAY_TYP = M,F,B                
         2 ID = 100                           
         2 FILTER = GTE
```

N.B. both solutions rely on the fact that `"` and `,` won't appear in the value for each of the sub-parts, excepting display_typ (where it's expected that `[` and `]` won't appear as part of the value).

---

For the case where the ID may or may not be enclosed in quotes (I wasn't sure if they would be sometimes), this should work:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 pkey, '"LOCT":"MA","PRICE":"10","DISPLAY_TYP": ["M","F","B"],"ID":101,"FILTER":"LTE"' str from dual union all
                     select 2 pkey, '"LOCT":"NY","DISPLAY_TYP":["M","F","B"],"ID":"100","PRICE":"30","FILTER":"GTE"' str from dual union all
                     select 3 pkey, '"LOCT":"OH","DISPLAY_TYP":["F","B"],"PRICE":"50","FILTER":"BOO","ID":"102"' str from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data containing your strings.
-- You would just run the SQL below, replacing "sample_data" with your tablename
select pkey,
       regexp_substr(str, '"LOCT":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) loct,
       regexp_substr(str, '"PRICE":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) price,
       replace(regexp_substr(str, '"DISPLAY_TYP":\s*\[(.*)\]', 1, 1, null, 1), '"') display_typ,
       regexp_substr(str, '"ID":"?([^",]*)"?', 1, 1, null, 1) id,
       regexp_substr(str, '"FILTER":"([^",]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) filter
from   sample_data;

      PKEY LOCT PRICE DISPLAY_TYP     ID    FILTER
---------- ---- ----- --------------- ----- ------
         1 MA   10    M,F,B           101   LTE   
         2 NY   30    M,F,B           100   GTE   
         3 OH   50    F,B             102   BOO
```

The `"?` in the regular expression means a doublequote must appear either 0 or 1 times at that point in the pattern.

If doublequotes will never be present around the ID value, then you could just use `'"ID":([^,]*)'` as the pattern.

Comment: Thank you it is working. The value for ID is not enclosed in double quotes. can you please tell me what do I need to get the results still in 1 row (1 MA   10    M,F,B           101   LTE )  '"LOCT":"MA","PRICE":"10","DISPLAY_TYP": ["M","F","B"],"ID":101,"FILTER":"LTE"'

Comment: I'll look at this tomorrow, when I'm back in the office.